# Implementing Fuzzines in Autocomplete in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have implemented elasticsearch autocomplete. This is the current query that I use (node.js - elasticsearcj.js):

```
body: {
            query: {
                match_phrase_prefix: {
                    schoolname: {
                        query: clientSearchterm,
                        slop: 10,
                        max_expansions: 50,
                         fuzzy : {
                            fuzziness : 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It works just fine. How do I implement Fuzziness parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just add this:

```
  "fuzzy" : {
            "fuzziness" : 2
          }
```